# How to modify a config file of tomcat docker container using ansible?

Tags: docker, tomcat, ansible

I am trying to change a config file or readme file of the running tomcat docker container using Ansible playbook. I went through docker modules where you can build and run your docker images. But I want to automate my task of changing or replacing any line in config file of container when it is running using Ansible. I don't see any such ansible module to do this. Any help is appreciated.

PS: I'm aware of `lineinfile` module which is used for modifying the line. My question is how do I enter into a running container using ansible.

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html

Comment: @helloV: Why downvote? I already know lineinfile and blockinfile. My question is how do i enter into the running container? After i enter into running container, i can use lineinfile.

Comment: I just commented. Didn't downvote. You can check in my profile if I downvoted your question.

Comment: @helloV: Sorry about that. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Anyone who wish to downvote, please leave a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to be using ansible with docker. It goes against the majority of advice on what docker containers are for and how they are to be used.

First, you want your containers to run a single process -- in this case, Tomcat. This means that you can't also run the ssh daemon. Second, when you update a config file you'll probably have to restart tomcat -- this will end the container's main process and cause it to exit, which is probably not what you want.

With docker, configuration is usually given via environment variables when the container is created. This is more likely to be the solution that you're after. There are many ways to provide this environment information, the easiest usually being the `-e` flag on the `docker run` command.

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense. Thanks!